# wordpress : Disable ftp in development version on ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, plugins, ftp

I run my own apache,and php for development and I installed a Wordpress blog but when I try to add plugins from admin it asks for FTP access. I don't use FTP and don't want to use.

I installed the ssh extension for PHP (`sudo apt-get install libssh2-php`)

But still it is asking FTP details .

Please help me out struggling from 2 hours .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Allow the webserver to write to the filesystem directly (`chown -R www-data wordpress`), it will not ask for FTP credentials if it can write directly.

Comment: @Geraid    i tried but still i am getting the same shouls i restart apache

Comment: That should not be nessecary. Make sure the owner of the wordpress directory (and the subdirectories) is the same user as the one the webserver runs on. If everything fails, in a secure development environment it should be safe to set write access for everybody with chmod, but that is a bad habit to get used to.